# R flexdashboard browser issue

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have developed an R Flex dashboard with runtime: shiny. I am able to run it on my system, but when I click on open on the browser, it's not opening on any of the browsers, the error, I am getting is "recover page".

Comment: Do you have any extensions that prevent loading of some elements, like javascript?

Comment: No. A very similar another Shiny App is getting opened on the browser with almost same amount of codes. But not this particular one. Thanks for the reply. Specifically, without the text mining chunk, if I am running the codes, I am able to open it on the browser but not with that piece of chunk.